# ASP.Net WebForms - Is it okay to populate List of SqlParamater in CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

We're handed down a 3-layer WebForms Application.

We have methods in DAL that accepts strongly-typed parameters as such:

```
    public Person GetPerson(int? personId, string personName = null)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.CommandText = "usp_GetPerson";
        command.Parameters.Add("@PersonId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = personId ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        command.Parameters.Add("@PersonName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = personName ?? (object)DBNull.Value;

        // run SqlCommand
    }
```

I'm trying to change the method that accepts a list of SqlParamater objects so we don't have to change the DAL codes often, especially that we regularly have requests to change/add/remove a lot of data being passed from our aspx pages to the database. This is something I want to implement:

```
    public Persons GetPerson(List<SqlParameter> sqlParameterList = null)
    {
        // initialize SqlCommand object and properties

        if (sqlParameterList != null)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameterList.ToArray());
        }

        // run SqlCommand
    }
```

Doing such will leave the DAL pretty much accept dynamic list of SqlParamater objects and we will only have to update the Stored Procedure and the CodeBehind should there be any changes in the parameters we need to accept. This also means that we have to populate the SqlParamater list in the CodeBehind of our aspx page, or should I do this in the BLL?

I don't have a solid understanding of what the different layers of an n-tier architecture so I'm a bit unsure what process have to put where. Currently, the BLL only acts as a link between the CodeBehind and the DAL without any Business Logic at all.

I'm also open to suggestions if there's a better way of implementing this.

Comment: This could be too broad a question and opinion based but I will add my input. Keep in mind part of the reason for the data layer is to keep it independent of the business and presentation layers. With your idea, now the consumer of the data layer needs knowledge of stored procedure parameters. This is **not** ideal

Comment: 4 years too late but Thanks @JonP. I finally understood why it's not ideal.

Comment: better late than never

Answer (score 0):

First Change your data access code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
namespace DAL
{
public class DataAccessLayer
{
    SqlConnection con = new 
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBCS"]);
    SqlCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds;
    SqlDataAdapter da;

    public void openConection()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
    }


    public void sendonly(string SP_Name, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        try
        {
            openConection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_Name, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

    }

    public DataSet getonly(string SP_Name)
    {
        try
        {
            openConection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_Name, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
        }
        return ds;

    }

    public DataSet sendget(string SP_Name, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        try
        {
            openConection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_Name, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            }
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

}

And Your Business Layer Should Be for insert

```
 public void Employee_Insert(string a, string b, int c , int d)
    {
        SqlParameter[] param1 = { 
                                new SqlParameter("@Name",a),
                                new SqlParameter("@Address",b),
                                new SqlParameter("@Age",c),
                                new SqlParameter("@country",d)
                                };
        _dal.sendonly("usp_Employee_insert", param1);
    }
```